# All member variables / functions of the JOptionPane class don't work / cant be accessed + Error during initialization of boot layer (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, initialization, joptionpane, boot

A couple days ago I started learning Java and I implemented an algorithm which outputs all results of the MU-puzzle over a certain amount of iterations.

The code worked perfectly fine until I decided to make it so that you have to enter the amount of iterations through a JOptionPane window.

When I tried to import javax.swing.JOptionPane, that didn't work, so I looked up a tutorial, which has helped me before in that matter, however, somehow it didn't work this time (this is the tutorial in case you're curious: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBzwSf8bEdQ).
Or I guess I should really say that it did fix the issue of import javax.swing.JOptionPane not being recognized by Eclipse (i.e. the red, squiggly line underneath it is gone).
But now whenever I try and access any member variables/functions of JOptionPane the program gives me an error and Intellisense doesn't even show the them in the first place, all it shows is class: Class<javax.swing.JOptionPane>.

Now all that happens when I try to compile my code is that I get this error message (even if I revert it back to its previously functional state):

[image: Error message]

So right now this is what my package (if that's the right term for it) looks like:

[image: Package structure]

This is my code (again please note that I'm a beginner so it's not perfect)

This version is the one with JOptionPane:
(all that was different in the other version that worked (but doesn't anymore), was that the JOptionPane line is missing, the function miuExecute() did not exist and the code inside miuExecute() was put directly into the main function with iterations being just a fixed positive integer)

```java
package miuSystem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        miuExecute();
    }   
     
    static void miuExecute() {
        int iterations = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of iterations you'd like to perform");
        
        String input = "MI";
        ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> miuIterations = new ArrayList<String>();
        miuIterations.add(input);

        for (int u = 0; u < iterations; u++) {
            for(int q = 0; q < miuIterations.size(); q++) {
                res.add(rule1(miuIterations.get(q)));
                res.add(rule2(miuIterations.get(q)));
                res.add(rule3(miuIterations.get(q)));
                res.add(rule4(miuIterations.get(q)));
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < res.size(); j++) {
                    if (j == i) {continue;}
                    else if (res.get(i).equals(res.get(j))) {
                        res.remove(i);
                        i--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("Iteration #"+(u+1)+":");
            System.out.println(res);
            System.out.println();
        
            miuIterations.clear();
            
            for(String s : res) {
                miuIterations.add(s);
            }
            res.clear();
        }
    }
    
    static String rule1(String input) {
        if (input.charAt((input.length())-1) == 'I') {
            return input+"U";
        }
        else {
            return input;
        }
    }
    
    static String rule2(String input) {
        String copy = "";
        for (int i = 1; i<input.length(); i++)
        {
            copy = copy + input.charAt(i);
        }
        
        return input+copy;
    }
    
    static String rule3(String input) {
        return input.replace("III", "U");
    }
    
    static String rule4(String input) {
        return input.replace("UU","");
    }
}
```

As already stated above, I tried following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBzwSf8bEdQ) but it didn't work.

Googling my problem(s) (both on and off of StackOverflow) also yielded either no result at all / results that I don't understand yet and would take too long to understand instead of just asking or results that didn't help me.

Edit: as requested here is what I think was meant by "show us the contents of your module-info.java" (if not please just tell what else you need) the part of the image thats censored is obv. just my name, which i don't like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukUQy.png)

Comment: Show us the contents of your `module-info.java`

Comment: i think i found what you needed @greg-449